# Cannot inject DbContext in repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dbcontext

I try to setup the DI for a new ASP.NET Core site and I have this code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    // Get the configuration from the app settings.
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    // Get app settings to configure things accordingly.
    var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
    var settings = new AppSettings();
    appSettings.Bind(settings);

    services
        .AddOptions()
        .Configure<AppSettings>(appSettings)
        .AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(config)
        .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(builder =>
        {
            builder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("myConn"));
        }, ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

    services.AddSingleton<ILoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository, LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository>();
        ...
```

Now, the `LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository` depends on the `MyDbContext`:

```
public class LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository : ILoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    ...
```

..and the DB Context is this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> ctxOptions) : base(ctxOptions)
    {
    }
}
```

When I run the application, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'MyCode.Infrastructure.Common.MyDbContext' while attempting to
>   activate
>   'MyCode.Infrastructure.LoadTestCleanUpService.LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository'.

I have tried changing the `ServiceLifetime` options and adding this extra code:

```
services.AddTransient<MyDbContext>(sp => new MyDbContext(config));
```

...but nothing seems to help and I cannot understand why this doesn't work. It does try to construct the repository, but why can't it construct the DB Context too? It doesn't even reach the point where I call `UseSqlServer()`!
Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1:**

Hmm... I now see this. Most likely it is related:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I have now :

- Replaced EF 6 with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Upgraded to netcoreapp2.2 target framework to solve some conflicting assembly versions.
- Made the repository scoped.

But I still get the same error.

Comment: Why MyDbContext class has AcDbContext for constructor? Is this code compile ?

Comment: @Dimitar Sorry. I've fixed that now. I "change" some parts of the code names to avoid leaking my project information. It is not any top secret stuff, but I try to make the code as "common" as possible.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and yes EF version mismatch is the only explanation for this

Comment: You cannot use a scoped database context within a singleton service. Trying to make the database context transient will also not fix that. Consider making your repository scoped itself instead.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to use EntityFramework 6 instead of EntityFramework Core here?

Comment: @poke I have added EF 6 by accident. I had the impression that VS would not let me add Full Framework packages in a Core app, but it seems I was wrong. :( I will also try making the repository scoped. I am a bit new to the Core Framework...

Comment: Be aware that your `MyDbContext` is held captive as a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) inside `LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository`.

Comment: @Steven Thanks. I have changed that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you have registered `LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository` as `Singleton` while `MyDbContext` as `Transient` and then you are trying to resolve `MyDbContext` from `LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository`. That's the problem. According to [ASP.NET Core Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes) documentation:

> It's dangerous to resolve a scoped service/transient service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

Solution is: register `LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository` and `MyDbContext` as follows:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionStringName")));

services.AddScoped<ILoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository, LoadTestCleanUpServiceRepository>();
```

Now problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks. After many changes, it worked. One thing that was really wrong was that I had defined two different DB contexts (accident after trying to move a single DB context) and that messed things up.